# Unable to create data integration connection set in power platform admin center

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, powerapps, dataverse, power-platform

I am trying to create a connection set between D365 CRM and D365 F&O inside the power platform admin center but when I select the destination environment it throws an error saying "Something went wrong" but there are no error IDs or logs I can see. Even when I switched the source and target environment around, it still throws the same error when I try to select the target environment.

Attached are two screenshots for reference.

[Connection details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HI4xC.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6GQI.png)

Is there anyone who has come across this issue already please advise how I can resolve this.

thank you.